# How to compare one getter method with return type as integer with a constant int variable in java

Tags: java, integer, compare

Here is my code :

```
public boolean isCalled() {
 if(getABC() == Constants.XYZ)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
  }
```

I need to get a boolean return value of my compare function. Is there a way to do this in smart way (just like `StringUtils.equals` for comparing strings)?

Comment: Thought I understood the question until you mentioned `StringUtils.equals`... They are integers, not strings. You said so yourself. Why would you want to use that?

Comment: @Michael I was just giving an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `if`. The `==` returns a boolean, and you can just return this directly:

```
public boolean isCalled() {
    return getABC() == Constants.XYZ;
}
```